# Using URL encoded parameters in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am passing an encoded URL to an AngularJS app, what I want to do is decode the value and then take the parameters to use them to fill some html elements. So I have the following encoded URL:

http://www.otherurl.com/ROOT/?Transaction=%257b%2522TransactionID%2522%253a%2522-1%2522%252c%2522CashierID%2522%253a506069%252c%2522ErrorDescription%2522%253a%2522%2522%252c%2522ErrorCode%2522%253a%2522%2522%252c%2522status%2522%253a500130%252c%2522statusName%2522%253a%2522Approved%2522%252c%2522TraceID%2522%253a%2522%2522%252c%2522externalID%2522%253a%2522%2522%252c%2522Amount%2522%253a45.00%252c%2522CurrencyCode%2522%253a%2522USD%2522%252c%2522RejectReason%2522%253a%2522%2522%252c%2522Notes%2522%253a%2522%2522%252c%2522CSID%2522%253a-1%252c%2522ProcessorName%2522%253a%2522%2522%252c%2522Descriptor%2522%253a%2522%2522%257d#/return

I have the following code on js:

```
var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent($location));
var nuevo = uri_dec.search()['Transaction'];

console.log('return controller > dec: ' + uri_dec);
console.log('return controller > nuevo: ' + nuevo);

$scope.transactionID = nuevo.search()['CashierID'];

console.log('return controller > transactionID: ' + $scope.transactionID);
```

Issue here is that Im not being able to use "nuevo" as it says undefined. Would you please help me solving this?

Comment: Can you please specify the issue you are facing?

Comment: Yes, im not able to get the cashierID parameter from the URL

Comment: **Transaction** Is this your first string in the query string?

Comment: Correct, after decoding the URL it should look like the following:

http://www.otherurl.com/ROOT/?Transaction={"TransactionID":"-1","CashierID":506069,"ErrorDescription":"","ErrorCode":"","status":500130,"statusName":"Approved","TraceID":"","externalID":"","Amount":45.00,"CurrencyCode":"USD","RejectReason":"","Notes":"","CSID":-1,"ProcessorName":"","Descriptor":""}#/return

Comment: please remove unwanted tags for angular 2.x

Comment: what do you mean for unwanted tags @user93?

Comment: there you go, thank you @user93

Comment: The JSON is broken. I think unwanted characters are adding in the query string in travel. Better stringify the JSON and encode it to a single value and pass it in the query string.

Comment: I am using the following code in c# to encode the values:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);

Comment: Why is this encoded _twice_ in the first place?

Comment: it is not encoded twice, it is just once, but for some reason to get the correct URL I need to decode it twice :S